# Regex to find variable names and their values in a text string

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have a random variable and value in a text string (str). What regular expression do I have to write to return the variable's name and value in an array?

```
str="var abcde = 'xyz';"
result = str.match(/.../); //<-??
//['abcde','xyz']; //value of result
```

I tried `/\bvar\s+([^;]+)/` but it will return the whole expression `abcde = 'xyz'` as a result.

It is always in the format of `var somename = somevalue;` somevalue can be a number, a string, an array or an object. So it can contain () and {} and commas.

Comment: I think we can safely say that you don't want to do this... Change the response from the server to something like JSON or just load it as a script if that's what you want.

Comment: That's not an option. I'd love to do that, but can't.

Comment: Well, your question just doesn't make any sense. I can't think of any sane scenario where you would even attempt this.

Comment: Sorry dude, this was not my decision to parse the text this way, i just got this task and have to do the job. I know it's the worst solution, but I also know that this can be done with regex. I'm just hoping that someone has the knowledge to help out with the regex syntax.

Comment: Np, just point your superior to here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript and have him point to this question. If he doesn't come around after that, find a new job. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

**Can't be done.**

**Well...**

You can try and parse javascript code to retrive the values of variables,
But, the problem is that will **only work if the value is string, arrays & objects that contains only string values**.
(lots if not most of the variables value will determine on runtime, and there nothing to do about that)

**So lets say it's only string values we want to find...**

It's not easy task to do, there are many forms to declear key and value

```
var hello = "world";
var hello = 'world';
var hello = "world", var2, var3 = 'value';
var hello = {
   prop: "world"
};
var hello = ["world"];
```

And many many more...

I can refer you to http://regexone.com/ if you still want to continue this approach.

Comment: It is always in the format of `var somename = somevalue;` somevalue can be a number, a string, an array or an object. So it can contain () and {} and commas.

Comment: you can use the following regex , /var\s[a-zA-Z0-9\_\$]+\s*?\=\s*?(\".*?\"|\'.*?\'|\[.*?\]|\{.*?\})/gm , note that it wont work for  nasted objects or nasted array

Comment: I tested this in chrome with `str = "var something = 'somevalue';"` and `str.match(/var\s[a-zA-Z0-9_\$]+\s*?\=\s*?(\".*?\"|\'.*?\'|[.*?]|\{.*?\})/gm);`. It returned `["var something = 'somevalue'"]`... Am I doing something wrong? I'd like to get `["something","somevalue"]`